# RegEx matching - stop first matching

Tags: php, regex

this string must be checked, with regex ...

```
<u>str<b>#u #bold<em>#u b #ital<strike>#u b em #ic stri</strike>ng</em>also(bold)</b></u><u>str<b>#u #boldalso(bold)</b></u>
```

This is the regex

```
[^.?]>#(.*?) #
```

The matching must be contained follow values

```
<b>#u #
<em>#u b #
<strike>#u b em #
<b>#u #
```

but only was matched

```
b>#u #
m>#u b #
e>#u b em #
b>#u #
```

what is wrong? i think this expression-part must be updated

```
[^.?]
```

Comment: What do you think `[^.?]` match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following regex :

```
<\w+>#[^#]*#
```

**Edit :**
Explanation of the expression :

- `<` : it starts matching from <
- `\w+` : followed by one or more letters
- `>`: and then closing >
- `#` : followed by #
- `[^#]*` : this will match just before of #
- `#` : and then #

so

```
<\w+>#          [^#]*            #        Final Match
---------------------------------------------------------
'<b>#'          'u '            '#'     '<b>#u #'
'<em>#'         'u b '          '#'     '<em>#u b #'
'<strike>#'     'u b em '       '#'     '<strike>#u b em #'
'<b>#'          'u '            '#'     '<b>#u #'
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your replay,

i modifed the expression

```
(<(\w+)>#([^#]*)#)
```

for this (e.g.) string

```
   <strike> #u #String:Underline-Strike-1<b>#u strike #String:Underline-Strike-Bold </b></strike><strike>#u #String:Underline-Strike-2</strike>
```

it was all matched, but not for

```
 <strike> #u #String:Underline-Strike-1
```

the WHITESPACE after ">" is the problem...

how to fix the regex?

**EDIT**

ok i find the solution by my self

```
\s*
```

final

```
(<(\w+)>\s*#([^#]*)#)
```